# push one more element to array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
return array(

    'User Management -> Role Management' => array(
        array(
            'permission' => 'role-management.view',
            'label'      => 'View',
        ),
        array(
            'permission' => 'role-management.create',
            'label'      => 'Create',
        ),
        array(
            'permission' => 'role-management.edit',
            'label'      => 'Edit',
        ),
        array(
            'permission' => 'role-management.delete',
            'label'      => 'Delete',
        ),
    ),

    'User Management -> User Management' => array(
        array(
            'permission' => 'user-management.view',
            'label'      => 'View',
        ),
        array(
            'permission' => 'user-management.create',
            'label'      => 'Create',
        ),
        array(
            'permission' => 'user-management.edit',
            'label'      => 'Edit',
        ),
        array(
            'permission' => 'user-management.delete',
            'label'      => 'Delete',
        ),
    ),

);
```

I have accessed this array successfully like this:

```
$permissions = Config::get('permissions');
```

I want to add new index below `label`. I have tried this but could not add. 
        `foreach ($permissions as $permission) {

```
        foreach ($permission as $eachPermission) {

            $encodedPermission = base64_encode($eachPermission['permission']);

            // $eachPermission['encodedPermission'] = $encodedPermission;
            array_push($eachPermission, "encodedPermission", $encodedPermission);             
        }
    }
    var_dump($permissions);  `
```

I have tried these but could not set the new index. My expected result was this:

```
'permission' => 'role-management.view',
'label'      => 'View',
'encodedPermission' => 'someencodedstring'
```

Am I doing it wrong or missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is multi-level, so you need to do double-foreach to reach the level required for your changes.

And for your changes being saved in the original array, you need to use ampersand (&) before your iterators to keep the reference to the original array. Without it, you would insert the new data only to the copy of the array that was created for your foreach loop.

This works:

```
foreach ($permissions as &$eachPermission) {
    foreach ($eachPermission as &$singlePermission) { 
        $encodedPermission = base64_encode($singlePermission['permission']);
        array_push($singlePermission, "encodedPermission", $encodedPermission);  
    }
}
var_dump($permissions);
```

Answer (score 1):

i would do it like this just because it is easier to understand ...

```
foreach($permissions as $name1=>$ar1){
    foreach($ar1 as $name2=>$ar2){
         $permissions[$name1][$name2]['encodedPermission'] = base64_encode($ar2['permission']);
    }
}
```